# Нужна запятая при уточнении места

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова Омск. И почему?
ООО гарантирует прием на работу Попова А.А. по прибытии на постоянное место проживания в город Омск Российской Федерации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение отредактировано: ООО гарантирует прием на работу Попова А.А. по прибытии в город Омск Российской Федерации на постоянное место проживания.

**Запятая не нужна,** обстоятельства неоднородные, так как указывают место (город Омск) и условие постоянства проживания.

Comment: Вы объяснили почему не нужна запятая между "город Омск Российской Федерации" и "постоянное место проживания". А автор спрашивает: "Нужна ли запятая после слова Омск", то есть между "Омск" и "Российской Федерации".